# Звездный рейтинг в цикле. Не могу передать id элемента из PHP в JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

Не получается передать id элемента из переменной PHP в js-скрипт.

Есть супер-простой вывод звезд рейтинга:

```
<div id="raiting_blank"></div>
<div id="raiting_votes"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  total_reiting = 4.5; // итоговый ретинг
  var star_widht = total_reiting*17 ;
  $('#raiting_votes').width(star_widht);
});
</script>


#raiting_blank { background:url(images/ratings.png); width:83px; } /* "Чистые" звездочки */
#raiting_votes {background:url(images/ratings.png) 0 -16px} /*  Закрашенные звездочки */
```

ПО ХОРОШЕМУ:
взять id страницы товара и прикрутить например к концу raiting_blank и raiting_votes чтобы в цикле у своего рейтинга был свой id и он закрашивал определенное количество ширины желтыми звездами.
Но оно так не работает хотя  я пару лет назад писал уже подобное и всё работало.

Что конкретно у меня не выходит:
я не могу никак  всунуть переменную на место #raiting_votes

```
$('#raiting_votes').width(star_widht);
```

я уже крутил и так

```
<?$ololo = '#raiting_votes';?>
$(<?=$ololo?>).width(star_widht);
```

и так

```
<?$ololo = '#raiting_votes';?>
$(<? echo $ololo;?>).width(star_widht);
```

и еще сто способов перепробовал и никак.

Самое интересное, что если я в скрипте делаю переменную:

```
ololo = '#raiting_votes';
$(ololo).width(star_widht);
```

оно работает, но если переменную вставляю извне, то нет!
Хотя когда средний рейтинг загоняю извне, то всё работает...

```
<?$total_rating = '4.5';?>
total_rating = <?=$total_reiting?>;
```

Непонятно, в чём проблема. Кто-то понимает как заставить это работать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зашел на этот вопрос только из-за эпичного названия)

Comment: не ну классно))

Comment: А у вас включен альтернативый синтаксис php? Попробуйте так `let total_reiting = <?php echo $total_reiting;?>` И в названии переменной ошибка rAting

Comment: @Vladik Поясните немного задачу. Вам надо просто передать параметр `php` в скрипт `js`? ID страницы Вы уже, как понял, получаете?

Comment: Мне нужно в этой строке $('#raiting_votes').width(star_widht); заменить #raiting_votes на переменную пхп . Но оно не хочет работать хотя и двумя строчками выше в total_reiting всё работает

Comment: А вы смотрели исходники получившейся страницы на клиенте (т.е. ctrl + u в браузере)? Что там в каждом случае получается в ваших попытках?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще довольно понятно, почему у вас не работает то, что вы пробудете. Возьмём попытку

```
<?$ololo = '#raiting_votes';?>
$(<? echo $ololo;?>).width(star_widht);
```

Чего вы ожидаете в получившемся html? Наверное,

```
$('#raiting_votes').width(star_widht);
```

а зря: скорее всего, после подстановки вы получите

```
$(#raiting_votes).width(star_widht);
```

т.к. кавычки входят в синтаксис php, а не в значение `$ololo`. Попробуйте вместо этого

```
<?$ololo = '"#raiting_votes"';?>
$(<? echo $ololo;?>).width(star_widht);
```

ожидаемый результат в этом случае -

```
$("#raiting_votes").width(star_widht);
```

т.е. должно заработать.

Comment: я пробовал не раб

Comment: @Vladik с подходом "не работает" вы не разберётесь в проблеме, надо вникать в детали. Посмотрите на получающийся html, как я предложил в комментарии к основному посту (или через dev tools), и добавьте результаты в ваш вопрос, тогда будет шанс, что вам помогут или вы сами разберётесь. Не надо тратить уйму времени на гадание вслепую

Answer (score 0):

When calling .width("value") any valid CSS measurement may be used for the width (such as 100px, 50%, or auto).

---

добавить нужно +"px" к числу